# How to disable pdf form fields while viewed by web browser?

Tags: pdf

I have fillable pdf form created by Adobe Acrobat DC Pro. By default, the form fields are highlighted by a blue rectangular box which can be prevented by the following document level javascript:

```
app.runtimeHighlight = false;
```

By the above code, the form fields are not highlighted any more if viewed by a pdf reader (eg: Acrobat or Nitro pro). But the form fields are still highlighted if the form is viewed by a web browser like google chrome.

Is there any document level javascript code by which form fields will not be highlighted viewed by the web browser as well?

Answer (score 1):

The highlighting of the fields is an application feature. This means you would have to control the viewer.

The PDF viewers built in web browsers are too "dumb" to understand (Acrobat) JavaScript. Therefore, the mentioned command does not work.

You may have to find the appropriate setting for the web browser, and set it from outside of the form.